# Handling geospatial coordinates in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, geospatial

I'm building a machine learning model where some columns are physical addresses (which I can translate into X / Y coordinates) but I'm a little bit confused on how this will be handled by the ML algorithm. 
Is there a particular way to translate a GEO location into columns for use into ML (classification and/or regression) ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Could you precise what you mean by "columns"? ML can be done with any kind of data... Could you precise your concern? (maybe giving samples of your data)

Comment: Hi @Eskapp , To simplify it to the maximum let's consider that I've a source postcode, a destination postcode and a transit time (from source to dest). I'd like to predict the transit time from source to destination. My concern is that a postcode has nothing to do with another one (no mathematical relation) so I thought about using coordinates but this splits the data into two different columns which should be related with something. In the end I'm wondering how to address this geospacial data for ML algorithms.

Comment: I would not see it as a split but only as multidimensional data (in your case the dimension will be 2). Machine learning algorithms exist for both unidimensional and multidimensional data. The two dimensions can be correlated or uncorrelated, depending on how you define your parameters in the model you choose afterwards. Does this answer your question, or am I missing something?

Comment: The "correlation" part is what I was missing. I need to read on how to make the algorithm aware of the correlation that exists in between X and Y. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: The correlation does not have to be explicitly set in most cases. Say, if you model you data by a Gaussian, when estimating the parameters of this Gaussian, the covariance matrix will have non-diagonal term that are non-zeros which will represent the data correlation. You only need not to take an assumption that states that the 2 dimensions are uncorrelated. If that answers you question I will submit a clear answer to this thread. :)

Comment: I understand from what you say that X and Y could be self-sufficient. As I'm saying bellow to @raghu I'll be using linear regression and random forest and I believe that adding some information that derives from the X Y could help, as he states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice of features would, in general, depend on what kind of relationship you anticipate between the features and the target variable. You are right in saying that post code number itself does not bear any relation to the target. Here the postcode is simply a string, or a category. What kind of model are you planning to use? Linear regression and Decision tree are two examples. These models capture relationships in different ways. As an example for a feature, you could compute the straight line distance between the source and destination, and use that in the model, since intuitively, the farther they are, the higher the transit time is likely to be. What else does the transit time depend on? See if you can relate the factors influencing the travel time to the information that you have, i.e., the postcodes / XY co-ordinates, in some way.

Comment: Hi @raghu, I'll be using mostly linear regression and rand forests. The distance thing is were I've also come too but did not push further. The interesting thing I'm learning for your comment is the question that I should ask myself "what does correlates the location to the transit time ?" which is the methodology I was using but without seeing the real question behind. I came to some interesting possible features like weather (I've the date time of travel), period of the year (holiday, etc ...). I'll keep this in mind for dealing with spacial information in this way.

Comment: Some extra features would be useful indeed. But we usually use ML also for bypassing this handmade modeling in many cases. If you have pairs data such as ({Coordinates_place1,Coordinates_place2},output), your model will try to infer itself  some sorts of correlation. However, if you want your output to be a transit time, for sure, coordinates won't be enough. Also, linear regression for such complex problems might not be recommended... A too simple model for a complex problem...

Answer (score 0):

This summarizes the answer we ended up with in the comments of the questions:

This transformation from ZIP codes to geo-coordinates should not be seen as a "split" but only as a way to represent your data in a multidimensional way (in this case the dimension will be 2). 
Machine learning algorithms exist for both unidimensional and multidimensional data. The two dimensions can be correlated or uncorrelated, depending on how you define the parameters of the model you choose afterwards.

Moreover, the correlation does not have to be explicitly set in most cases. Only an initial value may be useful, but many algorithm also rely on random initialization or other simple methods that estimate it from a subset of your data. So, for clarity's sake, if you model you data by a Gaussian for example, when estimating the parameters of this Gaussian, the covariance matrix will have non-diagonal term that are non-zeros which will represent the data correlation. You only need not to take an assumption that states that the 2 dimensions are uncorrelated!